# Single OSSEC rule to supress alert_by_email

Tags: email, rule, alerts, intrusion-detection

Im trying to supress/ignore the alert_by_email-option for every OSSEC-rule. The documentation suggests the following:

"Some rules have an option set to force OSSEC into sending an alert email. This option is alert_by_email. One of these rules is 1002. To ignore these rules you will have to create a rule to specifically ignore it, or overwrite the rule without the alert_by_email option."

However I could not find any example for creating a single role to ignore the option. Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule in your ossec/rules/local_rules.xml file:

Add the rule at the bottom of the file but make sure it is within the `<group>` tag.

```
<group>
   ...
   ..
   ...

    <rule id="1002" level="2" overwrite="yes">
      <options>no_email_alert</options>
      <description>Unknown problem somewhere in the system.</description>
    </rule> 
</group>
```

This will stop sending email alerts for rule id=1002